# Calcluating line heights, margins etc from baseline measurements

Tags: html, css, web, typography

I've been given a set of web pages to knock up, and one of the specifications from the designer is a set of vertical measurements from the baseline of fonts i.e. the height from the baseline to the block above is 50 pixels and to the block below to 30 pixels.

If I know the font size in pixel can anyone suggest a way to calculate the top and bottom margins (and / or line height etc).

Comment: Why don't you use `em` or `rem` units?

Comment: Its the spec that been given to me by the client so didnt really have a choice in what they used unfortunately.  Just have to work with what I've got

Comment: The position of the baseline depends on font. Presumable, the specs define the font family and size, too, so you should just do some testing to find suitable values.

Answer (score 0):

The line-height CSS property can be set as a numeric value. So the calculated line-height will be numeric value * font size. If you set line height to 1, then the line height will be equal to the font size. Here is an example with font-size: 20px

```
div {
font-size: 20px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
padding-top: 30px;
line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: im not too sure that would apply to what Im trying to do - I have a jpeg of a page im trying to build.  On that page is a heading - lets say "Welcome! How can we help".  The size of the heading font in px has been specified at 36 px.  the measurement to the element above from the baseline of the text was specified at 94 pixels, the measurement below at 46 pixels.  I need a way to arrive at those 94 and 46 pixels spacings using margins etc

Comment: In your case you must use margin instead of padding. The margin-top must be (94px - (font size * line height muliplier)).

Comment: that may just be what im looing for :)  I'll give that a go and see how it pans out - thanks for the quick replies :)

Comment: just one quick Q - how would i know what the line height multiplier is - theres nothing explicitly set in the css so far?

Comment: You can set it like in the example line-height: 1. You can choose it to be 1.1 or whatever. I am not sure what the default multiplier is. Probably it is different for the different browsers, so it's best to set it yourself.

Comment: This is pretty much the approach I took - You need to do a bit of playing around with the line-height property to get the bottom of the line on the baseline of the font and you can then set bottom margin = bottom pixel measurement and  top-margin = (pixel measurement - line height) - so in my example above i used line-height=19px, margin-top=75px (i.e. 94 - 19) and margin-bottom=46px.  Seems to do the trick so far.